# How can you make messages from the gmail API appear in threads?

Tags: python, gmail-api

I am sending out automated status reports via the Gmail API. These reports are being received by different colleagues using different mail clients.

The mails are showing up as separate mails in all clients. I would like them to thread together.

I have tried setting values for the 'References' and 'In-Reply-To' fields (I just made some values up), but it didn't work.

It used to work using the SMTP library and user and password authentication, but since Google turned that feature off and I had to switch to oauth2 it stopped working.

I'm using the python library by Google.

```
    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)

    message = email.message.EmailMessage() 

    message.set_content('This is automated mail')

    message['To'] = XX
    message['From'] = XX
    message['Subject'] = 'Automated'
    
    message.add_header('Reference','Automated')
    message.add_header('In-Reply-To','Automated')

    # encoded message
    encoded_message = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes()).decode()


    create_message = {
            'raw': encoded_message
    }
    send_message = (service.users().messages().send
                    (userId='me', body=create_message).execute())
```

Comment: If you want to stick with the smtp server either use an apps password instead of the users password.  Or you can use Xoauth2 there and send an access token.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for [Threads](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/threads)

Comment: I just made some values up  <-- i believe the value should be that of the previous message in the thread.